# should i separate user credentials and user tweets/posts in a different table or have them all in one table?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in PHP and we were tasked to do a web application using Laravel. And I was thinking of making a website like Twitter where users can register, login, logout, and create/delete/edit tweets of their own.

My question is, should I separate users credentials and the users' tweets in a different table? Or should I have them all in the same table? Can anyone tell me if what's the proper way to do it?

Comment: Realize that one user is going to have many tweets. Therefore, it makes more sense to have them separated

Comment: For better understanding of how database tables relationship works read some theory. In your case is logical to save user credentials in one table (maybe named users) and in other table (maybe tweets) you enter userID for every new tweet and then tweet text, date, etc. For example https://vladmihalcea.com/database-table-relationships/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one (not the only) proper way is to spin up different tables as aynber said. In your case, you could create a

- table called "**users**", which holds all user-account related data like user_id, username, surname, name, birthday, register_date, password, password_remember, password_reset_token and so on
- table "**tweets**", which has columns like "user_id", "tweet", "date", "views", "retweets", "comments" and so.

Keep in mind that "user_id" in table "tweets" is a foreign key (FK) of "user_id" from table "users". In Laravel this is called "Relationship".

*BTW: For creating tables in Laravel i would recommend to create a model and migrations:*
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-tables

IF you want to **create a model WITH a migration**, you can type
"php artisan make:model ModelName -m"
which automatically creates a migration file besides the model file.